# convert time format in android

Tags: java, android

i use a web API in my android app that passes me time in this format(current time): 1371645212

what is this? how i can convert it to regular time format?

Comment: to me seems a number (number of seconds).

Answer (score 3):

Looks like Unix/Epoch time to me.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

You can turn it into a `Date` object like this:

```
Date date = new Date(Long.parseLong("1371645212"));
```

Edit: looks like it's in seconds, not milliseconds, so multiply that number by 1000 first. That gives me the `Date` "Wed Jun 19 13:33:32 GMT+01:00 2013"

Answer (score 0):

**what is this?**

That is current time in milliseconds..

**how i can convert it to regular time format?**

try like this..

```
int seconds = (int) (milliseconds / 1000) % 60 ;
int minutes = (int) ((milliseconds / (1000*60)) % 60);
int hours   = (int) ((milliseconds / (1000*60*60)) % 24);
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert milliseconds into time format like this:

```
String time = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) -  
TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)), // The change is in this line
TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - 
TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));
```